# MATCH subtracting afterwards? MATCH (lookup;array;match_type) -1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

The question: if MATCH uses (lookup;array;match type) why there is a -1 after?

I have an Excel sheet at work that uses match in a way I cannot figure out.

The original formula:

```
=IF(E2<>"";OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$2;MATCH(E2;Streams;0)-1;0;COUNTIF(Streams;E2);1);ITID)
```

The break down for the MATCH's part is:

```
MATCH(E2;Streams;0)-1;
```

The lookup value "`E2`" contains selectable values from "Streams", which is a named list. This named list "Streams" contains non numeric values like:

```
LOG
PLTP
PTP
OTC
etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just understood that Match gives back the number position of the result, not the result itself.

Comment: Exactly, the =OFFSET function has some criterias (Reference, rows, cols.. etc). For the row criteria the match function is used in your example. So when match return a value, it's for the row number which Offset will use. By taking -1, you subtract one row to the number match will show as a result :)